Unable to Access BIOS or Boot Manager via HDMI Output on Laptop Running Ubuntu
I recently broke the screen on my laptop and have been using a secondary monitor connected via HDMI. However, I've encountered an issue where I'm unable to access the BIOS or boot manager on the external monitor during startup. The monitor only becomes active once Ubuntu has fully booted.
I've tried pressing various function keys during startup to access the BIOS, but it seems like the HDMI output isn't enabled until after the operating system loads. Is there a way to configure my laptop or Ubuntu to allow for HDMI output during the BIOS and boot manager stages?

Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

I don’t think this is anything to do with Ubuntu as it’s a problem before the os boots. I suggest look up your laptop model and see if there is any guidance from the manufacturer.

I'm pretty sure whatever you do in your OS (Ubuntu in this case) won't do anything to your BIOS, it will still only display on your primary monitor, in this case your laptop's screen (Correct me if I'm wrong). One way you can fix this and every other screen/monitor problem you might have in the future is by unplugging the display cable from the motherboard. Personally, I did that when I had my old laptop and it worked perfectly. It can be very easy or hard depending on your laptop model (and your skills :P).
